PDF Format Issue when Uploading Files with Flutter and FastAPI
I'm encountering an issue with my Flutter and FastAPI application when attempting to upload CBC parameters and a PDF file to a database. The Flutter function uploadImages() fetches CBC parameters and a PDF file using the /upload-images call. After obtaining this data, I then upload it to the database using an access token and the /reports call.
{"CBC_features":{"RBC":3.0,"MCV":80.0,"MCH":32.0,"MCHC":32.0,"RDWSD":50.0,"RDWCV":14.0,"PCT":0.2,"MPV":10.0,"PDW":20.0,"NEUTp":40.0,"NEUTn":4.0,"LYMp":50.0,"WBC":10.0,"MIDn":0.5,"MIDp":10.0,"PLT":150.0,"PLCR":15.0,"LYMn":0,"HGB":0,"HCT":0},"pdf_content":"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<…>

I've narrowed down the issue to the PDF file not being in the correct format. Below is the relevant Flutter and FastAPI code snippets:

Flutter:
Future<void> uploadImages() async {
    // Check if there are images to upload
    if (_images.isEmpty) {
      // Show a message to the user indicating that no images are selected
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        const SnackBar(
          content: Text('No images selected to upload'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
      return;
    }

    // Show a loading indicator while uploading
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(
        content: const Text('Uploading images...'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[900],
        duration: const Duration(
            days: 1), // Show indefinitely until upload is complete
      ),
    );

    try {
      // Prepare the list of files to upload
      List<MultipartFile> files = [];
      for (final image in _images) {
        // Convert file to multipart file
        files.add(await MultipartFile.fromFile(
          image.path,
          filename: image.path.split('/').last,
        ));
      }

      // Create a FormData object
      FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({'files': files});

      // Make an API request to upload images
      final response = await Dio().post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload-images',
        data: formData,
        options: Options(
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        ),
      );
      print(response);
      print(response.statusCode);

      // Check if the request was successful
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Extract CBC features and PDF content from the response
        final cbcFeatures = response.data['CBC_features'];
        final pdfContent = response.data['pdf_content'];

        // Convert the base64 encoded string back to bytes
        final Uint8List pdfBytes = base64Decode(pdfContent);

        // Construct the multipart file from the bytes
        final pdfFile = http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('pdf_file', pdfBytes,
            filename: 'report.pdf');

        // URL encode the access token
        final encodedAccessToken = Uri.encodeComponent(widget.accessToken);

        // Construct the URL for the report endpoint
        final reportUrl =
            'http://127.0.0.1:8000/reports?access_token=$encodedAccessToken';

        // Make a request to the /report endpoint using the extracted data
        final reportResponse = await Dio().post(
          reportUrl,
          data: {
            'cbc_features': cbcFeatures,
            'pdf_file': pdfFile,
          },
          options: Options(
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
            },
          ),
        );

        // Check if the report request was successful
        if (reportResponse.statusCode == 201) {
          print('reportResponse.statusCode == 201');
          // Show a success message to the user
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            const SnackBar(
              content: Text('Report created successfully'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.green,
            ),
          );
        } else {
          print('error message 1');
          // Show an error message to the user
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content:
                  Text('Failed to create report: ${reportResponse.statusCode}'),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
          );
        }
      } else {
        print('error message 2');
        // Show an error message to the user
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text('Failed to upload images: ${response.statusCode}'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      print('Error occurred: $error'); // Print the error message for debugging
      print('error message 3');
      // Show an error message to the user
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(
          content: Text('Error creating report: $error'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),
      );
    }
  }

FastAPI:
    @app.post("/upload-images")
    async def upload_images(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
        CBC_features = []
        result = {}
    
        pdf = FPDF()
    
        try:
            for idx, file in enumerate(files):
                contents = await file.read()
    
                # ------------ OCR Start ------------
                print("OCR started")
                response = await ocr(file, contents)
                CBC_features.append(response)
    
                print(f"Received file: {file.filename}, OCR: {response}")
                # ------------ OCR End ------------
    
                # ------------ Image2PDF Start ------------
                # Convert image data to PNG format
                image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(contents))
    
                page_width, page_height = 210, 297  # A4 dimensions in mm
                image_width, image_height = image.size
                scaling_factor = min(page_width / image_width, page_height / image_height)
    
                new_width = image_width * scaling_factor
                new_height = image_height * scaling_factor
    
                x = (page_width - new_width) / 2
                y = (page_height - new_height) / 2
    
                with io.BytesIO() as temp_buffer:
                    image.save(temp_buffer, format="PNG")
                    temp_buffer.seek(0)
                    png_data = temp_buffer.read()
    
                # Write PNG data to a temporary file
                with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.png') as temp_file:
                    temp_file.write(png_data)
                    temp_file_path = temp_file.name
    
                # Add a page to the PDF
                pdf.add_page()
    
                # Add image to the PDF using the temporary file path
                pdf.image(temp_file_path, x=x, y=y, w=new_width, h=new_height)
    
                # Delete the temporary file
                os.unlink(temp_file_path)
                # ------------ Image2PDF End ------------
        except Exception as e:
            print('error in OCR:', idx, e)
    
        print('-------> CBC_features:', CBC_features)
    
        try:
            # Extract the first value for each key
            for features in CBC_features:
                for key, value in features.items():
                    if key not in result or (key in result and value != 0):
                        result[key] = value
            print('final result:', result)
        except Exception as e:
            print('error in compression:', e)
    
        pdf_path = "pdf/output.pdf"
        pdf.output(pdf_path)
        with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
            pdf_bytes = pdf_file.read()
    
        print("PDF saved successfully.")
    
        pdf_base64 = base64.b64encode(pdf_bytes).decode('utf-8')
    
        return {"CBC_features": result, "pdf_content": pdf_base64}

@app.post("/reports", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_report(cbc_parameters: List[str], pdf_file: UploadFile = File(...), db: Session = Depends(get_db),
                        current_user: models.User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    try:
        print(cbc_parameters)
        # print(pdf_file)
        print(current_user.id)

        pdf_content = pdf_file.file.read()

        # Create report instance
        db_report = models.Report(cbc_parameters=cbc_parameters, pdf=pdf_content, owner_id=current_user.id)

        # Add report to the database
        db.add(db_report)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(db_report)
        print("db updated")

        print("running CBC model....")
        await cbc_model(username=current_user.username, user_id=current_user.id, db=db)
        print("model run complete!")
    except Exception as e:
        db.rollback()
        print(e)
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, detail=str(e))

